# What neutron spectrum should be produced from a low level nuclear fission event?

Tags: nuclear-physics, spectroscopy, neutrons, explosions

I am trying to determine what neutron spectrum would be produced by a low level nuclear event (for example a tactical nuclear weapon).  What ratio or combination of thermal, slow, and fast neutrons would be created?  I've been looking for this information in various publications with no success. Perhaps I'm just not looking in the right places?

Comment: This must be in classified information as it is useful for weapon construction.

Comment: Look at this, about 1/3 of the way down. https://www.lanl.gov/science-innovation/science-highlights/2017/2017-08.php  Also, Nuclear Data Sheets (pay site) and the Evaluated Nuclear Data files (free, but you'll have to extract the data yourself.)

Comment: Thanks for the LANL.gov reference.  That is information I was familiar with but a good reminder.  So far the real challenge is understanding the spectra and, as is mentioned in another post, the thermalizing effects in atmosphere.

Answer (score 1):

A full and detailed answer can only be had with a detailed simulation tuned on actual test data.

A (very) rough answer would be

> *"once you are many times the scattering length in air away from the core event you should expect a thermal distribution"*

just on general principles, but the interesting question will be how the conditions immediately after the detonation re-set the baseline for measuring "many times the scattering length" (that is how far do prompt neutron get before the predominant dynamic consideration is stochastic scattering in the environment).

Comment: It would be nice to have actual test data but fortunately that is not directly available. Also, in this instance, there is insufficient information to create a proper Monte Carlo simulation.   I've also run some of my own Bayesian based evaluations on the data I have. I'm going to have to go with a broader range on the spectra than I would like. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You might get some useful info from this paper: [Evaluation of the Prompt Fission Neutron Spectrum of
Thermal-neutron Induced Fission in U-235](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S1875389215001236/1-s2.0-S1875389215001236-main.pdf?_tid=d9d4b8d8-0cf6-11e8-ad83-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1518111679_8a3eee8610c31e092d63c058027a6627)

What are you trying to get at, ultimately? Presumably, you're not actually trying, at this moment, to evaluate collected data to detect tactical nuclear weapons detonations, so we might be able to help if you include more details.